# Why is this a never-ending loop?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The file that is being used as input is a .txt file that contains:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

And it is being opened on the 3rd line of my code. Yet the while loop never terminates, continuously print "Pass" to the console, so why is it not finding `infile.eof()` after the 5th line of text?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("TEST.txt", ios::in);


    if(infile.is_open()){
        while(!infile.eof()){
            cout << "Pass" << '\n';
        }
    }
    else{
        cout <<"Fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you would read something, checking `eof` or `bad` is not the proper way to read from a `ifstream`.

Answer (score 6):

Because you never actually consume (read) anything from infile to advance the file pointer.    The code just continually checks for EOF, but doesn't actually read any contents of the file.

Comment: How can I change my code to consume the data from the file?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Definitely something to remember in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you don't do anything infile which causes an infinite loop. As to your question of how to do this right, try this:

```
int main()
   {
      ifstream infile("TEST.txt", ios::in);
      string input;
      while(infile)
      {
          getline(infile, input);
          <do something with "input">
      }
      return 0;
   }
```